# renaming angularjs service name in webstorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Given an angularjs service defined as  `appModule.service('SomeService', function ($resource)`, how can I use webstorm (with the angularjs plugin installed) to refactor/rename `SomeService` and propagate the changes?

Comment: Right click on the name string, then choose refactor. That should do it.

Comment: 'rename' is not selectable

Comment: I would then assume that this is not possible since Webstorm doesn't recognize the string as refactorable. A string can't be renamed.

Comment: not currently possible. More advanced AngularJS support is planned for WebStorm 8

Comment: @lena WebStorm 8 is out now. :)